# Использование кнопки ZOOM на Logitech Performance Mouse MX в Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, железо, hotkeys, мышь

На этой мыши есть несколько физических кнопок. На данный момент я активно пользуюсь только двумя из них - вперёд и назад - для навигации по истории браузера. Рядом с этими двумя кнопками есть третья (подписана как Zoom), но в Ubuntu без дополнительных настроек не работает.
Как сделать, чтобы её нажатие было эквивалентно нажанию `Ctrl+W` на клавиатуре? Нужно, чтобы нажатие этой кнопки закрывало текущую вкладку в бразере

**UPDATE**: xev

```
ButtonPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x4400001,
    root 0x2a8, subw 0x0, time 56484217, (168,175), root:(767,623),
    state 0x10, button 13, same_screen YES

ButtonRelease event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x4400001,
    root 0x2a8, subw 0x0, time 56484352, (168,175), root:(767,623),
    state 0x10, button 13, same_screen YES

LeaveNotify event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x4400001,
    root 0x2a8, subw 0x0, time 56484611, (168,175), root:(767,623),
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor, same_screen YES,
    focus NO, state 16

EnterNotify event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x4400001,
    root 0x2a8, subw 0x0, time 56484612, (168,175), root:(767,623),
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor, same_screen YES,
    focus NO, state 16

KeymapNotify event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  4294967208 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: для начала: с помощью *xev* установите, какие именно x-события происходят при нажатии и отпускании этой кнопки.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin обновил

Comment: [это](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ManyButtonsMouseHowto) должно помочь.

Comment: спрашивал я про вывод *xev* для того, чтобы удостовериться, что мышь при нажатии этой кнопки генерирует именно *button[press|release]-события*. ведь, теоретически, мышь могла выставить дополнительно и «клавиатурный» интерфейс, и через него отправлять *key[press|release]-события*. тогда надо было бы «идти другим путём».